# Teleporting Grabbed Allies

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

I have a guy in my group who seems hellbent that if he grabs an ally, he can teleport with them. Couldn't find anything in the PHB so I'm asking if anyone has any hard evidence against this. Really getting frustrating. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can only bring a grabbed ally along when you teleport if you have teleportation as a movement speed, *not* if you use a power to teleport.**

From the Rules Compendium, p244 (emphasis mine):

> **Move a Grabbed Target**
>   *Action*: **Standard action**
>   *Strength Check*: The creature makes a Strength check opposed by the Fortitude of the target it is grabbing. The check automatically succeeds if the target is a *helpless* ally of the creature.
>   *Success*: The creature can move up to half its speed and pull the target with it. The creature's movement doesn't provoke an opportunity attack from the grabbed target, but the movement otherwise provokes opportunity attacks as normal.

Moving a grabbed target is a **standard action**. Unless you have teleportation as a movement speed and therefore don't need to activate a power to teleport, you can't bring anyone with you; this is because you can't take two different actions simultaneously.

Comment: Would this also apply if the teleport power is a move action?

Comment: Yes, it still applies then. Moving a grabbed target *is itself* an action. You can use an action to activate a teleportation power, or you can use an action to move a grabbed target, but you can't do both at the same time. If you have teleportation as a movement mode, then you just move a grabbed a target, and teleportation just happens to be how you move.

Comment: Ahh! Perfect. That works.

Comment: There's also many feats, powers, and features that allow you to teleport adjacent allies along with you when you teleport. Several of them are specific to Fey Step. In those cases, you don't even need to grab your ally first.